# Is it possible to plugin create cordova for ionic 3 with Epson ePOS SDK for iOS?

Tags: javascript, ios, objective-c, cordova-plugins, ionic3

I never created a Cordova plugin, so I would like just know if it's possible to create Cordova plugin  for ionic 3 (only ios) with this https://download.epson-biz.com/modules/pos/index.php?page=soft&scat=58 . And can you tell me please what file I need to use for creating a Cordova plugin  (only for printing some text). I will put it in git after creating because I need it and show it to some people who need it. I just understand the JavaScript part of it but not objective-c... Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Really nice idea. You can start by using below link. Good luck!

[**iOS Plugin Development Guide**](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/ios/plugin.html)

> This section provides details for how to implement native plugin code
>   on the iOS platform. Before reading this, see [Plugin Development
>   Guide][plugin-dev] for an overview of the plugin's structure and its
>   common JavaScript interface. This section continues to demonstrate the
>   sample echo plugin that communicates from the Cordova webview to the
>   native platform and back.
>
> An iOS plugin is implemented as an Objective-C class that extends the
>   CDVPlugin class. For JavaScript's exec method's service parameter to
>   map to an Objective-C class, each plugin class must be registered as a
>    tag in the named application directory's config.xml file.